# angular ui typeahead displaying non matching strings

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I have configured the ui.bootstrap typeahead plugin as below:

```
  <input type="text" 
          placeholder="Pick a stock" 
          ng-model="stock" 
          typeahead="stock.symbol + ' ' + stock.companyName for stock in stockList" 
          class="form-control input-sm" 
          typeahead-min-length=2 
          typeahead-wait-ms=0>
```

The expected behavior is that if I type in "face" .. i would expect only strings with "face" to be displayed in the drop-down. but currently you will notice that all strings get displayed. Irrespective of what you type.. all strings in the `$scope.stockList` get displayed.

How do I ensure that only the matching strings are displayed ?

[Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NowvK4aUuA0hepUZ0gXy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to display only matched values you need to apply filter on `$viewvalue` populated by the typeahead directive.

```
<input type="text" 
 ...
  ng-model="stock" typeahead="stock.symbol + ' ' + stock.companyName for stock in stockList 
  | filter:$viewValue" ...>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/04Lj1Acv935bbjuW1IXu?p=preview)**

This is a generic filter that will match characters typed in for all the fields in the object, if you want to selectively match on a specific field say `companyName` specify the filter accordingly, ie

```
 | filter:{companyName:$viewValue}"
```

> The sourceArray expression can use a special $viewValue variable that corresponds to the value entered inside the input.